# embedded Linux RAM usage and confusion

Tags: memory, embedded-linux, yocto, ram

I am trying to optimize RAM for an embedded Linux.
Running in same hardware, pretty much same software one is old version (yocto morty) and another is new version (Yocto dunfell).

```
free for new version
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          57568       41020        2036         324       14512       12520
Swap:             0           0           0
free for old version
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          57496       34120        2588         284       20788       19516
Swap:             0           0           0
```

I can see used memory increase about 7M for new version.
when I do `ps axo pid,rss,cmd  | awk '{sum+=$2} END {print sum }'`
and sum up all the RSS value for my system.
I found my new version(83652K) actual less than old version(124240K). Nearly every process RSS is smaller than old version.
It does not make sense to me.
So I use the `cat /proc/meminfo` to get more detail.
I found the key different is `Active(anon) and AnonPages`. New version increases 6M.
But I don't know where this 6M comes from and how to trace it.
Thanks

```
*****************new version***********************
MemTotal:          57568 kB
MemFree:            1460 kB
MemAvailable:      14752 kB
Buffers:             132 kB
Cached:            11760 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            31456 kB
Inactive:           4044 kB
Active(anon):      23720 kB
Inactive(anon):      212 kB
Active(file):       7736 kB
Inactive(file):     3832 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                12 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         23628 kB
Mapped:             6712 kB
Shmem:               324 kB
Slab:              10464 kB
SReclaimable:       5300 kB
SUnreclaim:         5164 kB
KernelStack:        1496 kB
PageTables:         1948 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:       28784 kB
Committed_AS:     651316 kB
VmallocTotal:     958464 kB
VmallocUsed:        1228 kB
VmallocChunk:     951436 kB

***********old version**************************************************
MemTotal:          57496 kB
MemFree:            1996 kB
MemAvailable:      19172 kB
Buffers:             908 kB
Cached:            12092 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            30168 kB
Inactive:            812 kB
Active(anon):      18048 kB
Inactive(anon):      216 kB
Active(file):      12120 kB
Inactive(file):      596 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                52 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         17984 kB
Mapped:             5984 kB
Shmem:               284 kB
Slab:              14188 kB
SReclaimable:       8036 kB
SUnreclaim:         6152 kB
KernelStack:        1480 kB
PageTables:         2120 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:       28748 kB
Committed_AS:     649728 kB
VmallocTotal:     958464 kB
VmallocUsed:        1228 kB
VmallocChunk:     951556 kB
```